# VBA Store current sheet name to use on new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am wanting to have excel remember the active sheet name and then delete the active sheet and copy a different sheet that i use as a template and rename the new sheet with the stored name from the deleted sheet.

This is the code im using i just need to have it rename the sheet with the stored sheet name

```
Sub Reset_Work_Order()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete


Dim NewSht              As Worksheet

Master_Work_Order.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
Set NewSht = ActiveSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Excel's Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1).  Turn the recorder on, perform the action manually and then review the VBA Excel has written for you.  This technique is great when you know what you want, but not how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Reset_Work_Order()

Dim ShtName As String
Dim Master_Work_Order As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set Master_Work_Order = Worksheets("YourMasterSheetsName")

' keep name of ActiveSheet
ShtName = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.Delete

Dim NewSht              As Worksheet

Master_Work_Order.Copy After:=ActiveSheet

Set NewSht = ActiveSheet
' set new copied sheet name to Previous ActiveSheet's name
NewSht.Name = ShtName

End Sub
```

Comment: would it be passable to use the sheets code here `Set Master_Work_Order = Worksheets("YourMasterSheetsName")` instead?

Comment: you mean the `Sheet.Index` ? like `Worksheets(2)` ? the sheet in the 2nd position in the Workbook ?

Comment: Sorry meant to say, the sheets CodeName instead.

Comment: can you explain better , like what do you want to use ?

Comment: @luke - yes, if the sheet's codename is already `Master_Work_Order`, then you don't need the `Set Master_Work_Order` statement, or the `Dim Master_Work_Order` statement.  They are implicitly done by Excel.